# Как создать БД для бота

Tags: база-данных, vkontakte-api, разработка-игр, книги

Разрабатываю бота в vk
Идея в том, чтобы создать бота рассказывающего интерактивную историю.

Что сделано:
Я написал самого бота, то есть отправка сообщений и сам бот работает правильно.

В чем вопрос:
Проблема в том, что я не понимаю как оформить саму базу данных для бота.

Как должно работать:
Логика такая, есть мини текст, который должен вывести бот пользователю, пользователь выбирает какое-то действие и бот выдаёт ему результат этого действия
Например, у меня есть 3 линии развития сюжета.
Пользователь выбирает 1 ветку и собственно бот должен дальше посылать пользователю текст и события первой ветки.
При этом ветки сюжета могут и сплетаться в одну в каких-то местах, ну то есть такая стандартная книга, но с выбором действий.

И вот как мне лучше организовать саму бд? По сути это будет база данных, которая хранит листочки от книги(утрировано)
У меня была идея создавать отдельно таблички для каждой сюжетной линии, но мне кажется это очень громоздким и трудоемким процессом.
Есть ли способы, как это лучше всего организовать?
Буду рад любому совету или примеру

Comment: **Пользователь выбирает 1 ветку** Если веток одновременно больше одной, то табличка типа `id, userid, bookid .....` нужна...